# Will two masses connected by a rod sliding on a frictionless surface lift off?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

> Consider the following simplified model of a skater falling over: Two equal masses *m* are attached to opposite ends of a light, straight rod of length 2. One mass rests at (0,0) on a *frictionless* horizontal surface and the other is balanced, rather precariously, vertically above it at (0,2). The system is disturbed slightly. Find the (*x*, *y*) coordinates of the two masses when the angle of the rod to the vertical is *θ*.
>
> The lower mass loses contact with the frictionless surface when the horizontal velocity of the lower mass is a maximum. Why? What is the value of cos *θ* when this happens?

[https://web.archive.org/web/20120130215955/http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~read/TQP2.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20120130215955/http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Eread/TQP2.pdf)

I thought the (*x*, *y*) coordinates of the lower and higher mass respectively would be (-sin*θ*, 0) and (sin*θ*, 2cos*θ*). [image]

However, I am unable to work out why the lower mass would ever lose contact with the frictionless surface. When the horizontal velocity is at a maximum, the horizontal acceleration should be 0, indicating that Tsin*θ* is 0. So the tension force would either be 0 or acting vertically, and it is not going to be acting vertically as 0 < *θ* < pi/2 whilst the rod is falling. Therefore, the tension forces would be 0 and I think the lower mass would then be in equilibrium and so it would not be lifting up. Additionally, I would think that the lower mass would lose contact when the reaction force acting upon it is 0 however, this would lead to unequal radial accelerations on the two masses, which I thought couldn't be possible perhaps because it would break the rod.
Also, this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516203/will-a-falling-rod-stay-in-contact-with-the-frictionless-floor) seems to suggest that the reaction force being 0 is impossible and so the lower mass wouldn't lose contact ever. So, is the question wrong or am I missing something important. [image: What I think the forces on the two masses are]